# Combining 2 views into one in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, union

I need to do something completely insane. I have 2 views that have the same number of columns (different column names though except the ID column) and they both happen to have
2 existing UNION queries. From my understanding `UNION` and `UNION ALL` only work when combining 2 `SELECT` queries, here I'm trying to combine 4 of them! Aka the 2 views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"from my understanding UNION and UNION ALL only work when combining 2 SELECT Queries"

[Ummmm...no](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/queries-union.html).  You can do something like the following:

```
select col1,col2
from table
union all
select col1,col2
from some_other_table
union all
select col1,col2
from yet_another_table;
```

etc, etc.

Comment: Okay but I'm not querying tables, I'm querying views will it work if I do from view?

Comment: @user1183513 - Yes.  As per [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/queries-union.html), "Set operations can also be nested and chained [on queries]".

Comment: @user1183513: A view is just a special table in PostgreSQL. You can use it anywhere in a SELECT statement where you could use a table, too. (It's different with INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE.)

Comment: Doing 

SELECT *
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM Table2;

gets me


ERROR:  relation "table1" does not exist

Comment: @user1183513 - Then the table doesn't exist.  Create it.  Also "fsview_table1" isn't mentioned in your `select` statement...

Comment: sorry I meant table1 doesn't exist. but keep in mind they aren't tables they're actually views.

Comment: Then it doesn't exist.  Create it or don't query from it.

Comment: @user1183513 - I just tested out a `union` between two different views and it worked fine (on PostgreSQL 8.2.13), and likewise with a `union all`.  Either one of your views doesn't exist or one of the tables mentioned in one of your views doesn't exist.

Comment: Sweet, turns it that Postgres is case senstive to the point that, even if my Views had capital letters in some parts, and that my queries had the caps at the exact same spot, it wouldn't take it as it HAS to be lowercase, you've been helpful, I'm def giving you the checkmark, thanks.

Comment: Oh one more thing, it's not pulling out the columns that I have given different names, on the table that I'm joining through the Union, is there a way to get around that?

Comment: A `union` (or `union all`) sticks with the column names given in the first query, so if those aren't the final column names that you want, you'll have to rename them there.

Comment: Well lets say I have View1 and it's got `BreakfastID, Eggs, Toast` for it's columns and View2 has the samething, but I want to combine them so that it looks like this: `BreakfastID, Eggs, Eggs1, Toast, Toast1` is there an easy way?

Comment: Well you can't get that with a `union all`, as that appends the columns of the second query to the first.  If the first view has `breakfastid, eggs, toast` and the second view has `breakfastid,eggs1,toast1`, then you can join the two views on `breakfastid`.